# How to mock react components with react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I have a react component, which has two children, like this:

```
import {Child1} from './child1';
import {Child2} from './child2';
...
return (
  <>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
  </>
)
```

I'm using react `testing-library` and the app as created with `create react app` and not ejected.
I'd like to mock them in my unit test, since they have their own tests, so I'm trying to:

```
jest.mock('./child1', () => 'some mocked string');
jest.mock('./child1', () => 'some mocked string');
```

But when I render it using `import { render } from '@testing-library/react';` I see the following `Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined`.

Why is that and how do I mock those components?

Answer (score 21):

`child1` and `child2` modules use named export to export their component. You should mock the named export component `Child1` and `Child2`.

The below example mocks these two modules and their component with the stateless functional components.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import { Child1 } from './child1';
import { Child2 } from './child2';

import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
    </>
  );
}
```

`child1.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function Child1() {
  return <div>child1</div>;
}
```

`child2.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function Child2() {
  return <div>child2</div>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import App from './';

jest.mock('./child1', () => ({ Child1: () => 'mocked child1' }));
jest.mock('./child2', () => ({ Child2: () => 'mocked child2' }));

describe('67636326', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const { container } = render(<App />);
    expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div>
        mocked child1
        mocked child2
      </div>
    `);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67636326/index.test.tsx (8.339 s)
  67636326
    ✓ should pass (25 ms)

 › 1 snapshot written.
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot written from 1 test suite.

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 written, 1 total
Time:        9.454 s
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was a matter of declaring the mock outside the `describe`. It works now. 
Any explanation on why it fails (meaning it doesn't mock and renders the real component) if I bring `jest.mock(...)` inside the `describe` block?

Answer (score 1):

if you try to render a module.export, you should try this way

```
jest.mock('../components/Modal', () => () => <div>ModalMocked</div>);
```

in order to contribute to another solutions